# Bin(n,p) - do a simple maximum likelihood without knowing maximum likelihood.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ follows $Bin(n,p)$. For any given $k=0,1,...,n$ what value of $p$ maximizes $P(X=k)$?

Alternatives

1. $n / (n+k)$
2. $k^2 / n^2$
3. $1 - k/n$
4. $k / n$

I try to look at the pmf of Bin, but I cannot see how to solve this. (It's a "pick 1 2 3 or 4"-quesiton, so a bit of thought is ok - no proof or calculation needed).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try differentiating $P(X=k)$ with respect to $p$. The answer is $k/n.$